# How to automatically login to a website using username and password. Then download file to local computer

Tags: authentication

I would like to use some sort of scripting language to perform the following operations:

1) Login to a website using username and password
2) Download a file from the website to local c: drive

Thanks

Comment: What kind of a website? Do you need to connect using a secure connection? What kind of authentication does the website use? Does the file have a known URL or will you have to search for it at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Login is a complex operation which can be tedious implemented by hand.

I recommend using Selenium for this task

Regards